# Make grid column width give its value to the row height?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a grid where all grid area parts are squares (grid column width = grid row height).
It should be responsive and the device width should decide the 1fr width value (see below).

```
#gridParent {
     margin: 5rem 14rem;
}

#grid {
     grid-template-areas:
            "a a b b"
            "a a c d"
            "e e f f"
            "g g f f"
            "k l h h"
            "i i j j";

     grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
     gap: 2rem;
}
```

---

```
<div id="gridParent">
    <div id="grid">
        <div class="gridItem"></div>
        <div class="gridItem"></div>
        <div class="gridItem"></div>
        <div class="gridItem"></div>
        <div class="gridItem"></div>
        <div class="gridItem"></div>
        <div class="gridItem"></div>
        <div class="gridItem"></div>
        <div class="gridItem"></div>
        <div class="gridItem"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

now I would like to somehow calculate the rows height so the it is the same as the 1fr column width **pixelwise**(!)

`grid-auto-rows: auto;` is not working for me.

`grid-auto-rows: 1fr;` same goes for this.

Basically every grid area part ( every single "a" from the 2x2-"a" should be a sqare...) is that possible to do?

I also tried aspect ratio but this doesnt work with the 2x2 area parts and the 1x1 or 2x1 area parts in one row...

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE] with the HTML?

Comment: Will you accept a javascript solution?

Comment: you need a different ratio for each case. aspect-ratio:1 for the square are and 2 for 1/2 for the others

Comment: Aspect ratio 2 /1 doesnt work because you have the gap of 2rem, i tried that too...

Comment: javascript is fine for me :)

Comment: you have 6 rows so set the aspect ratio on the container (4/6)

Comment: oh this might work - i will try; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with aspect-ratio:

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
   "a a b b" 
   "a a c d" 
   "e e f f" 
   "g g f f" 
   "k l h h" 
   "i i j j";
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr; /* equal rows and ... */
  gap: 2rem;
}

/* ... set the ratio of only one square element */
.a {
 grid-area: a;
 aspect-ratio: 1;
}

.gridItem {
  background: red;
}
.b {grid-area:b}
.e {grid-area:e}
.f {grid-area:f}
/* and so on ..*/
```

```html
<div id="gridParent">
  <div id="grid">
    <div class="gridItem a"></div>
    <div class="gridItem b"></div>
    <div class="gridItem e"></div>
    <div class="gridItem f"></div>
    <div class="gridItem"></div>
    <div class="gridItem"></div>
    <div class="gridItem"></div>
    <div class="gridItem"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but is 1 vertical fr = 1 horizontal fr? because if not here is my problem: if you put content in the grid items, the vertical 1fr will "look" for the biggest height-value and apply it to all the others... and then there are no more squares but rectangles... or am i wrong?